# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in Rserve using Java

Tags: java, r, rserve

Getting exception when I assign large String value to Rserve in Java

```
 public void run(String data) {//800
        RConnection c =null;
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
         
            c = new RConnection();
            if (c.isConnected()) {
                System.out.println("*** R serve is connected..");
            } else {
                System.err.println("R serve is not available");
            }             
            System.out.println("data set length-->"+data.length());
            c.assign("poleData",data);//This line is throwing error
         
            c.eval(String.format("source(" + rScript + ")"));
            REXP result =c.eval("imputResult");


         System.out.println("Completed.."+imputeData.toPrettyString());
            long endTime = System.nanoTime();
            //System.out.println("Time end -->"+endTime);
            long duration = endTime - startTime;
            //   System.out.println("Total time diff in nanosecond-->"+(endTime-startTime));
            double diff = (double) duration / 1000000000;
            //    System.out.println("Total time diff -->" + diff + " second");
            // c.close();
        } catch (RserveException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(c!=null) {
                c.close();
                System.out.println("Connection closed..");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Exception**

*** R serve is connected..
data set length-->58784021
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 8452396 out of bounds for length 8452396
at org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RConnection.assign(RConnection.java:254)
at com.app.ImputaionJson$Task.run(ImputaionJson.java:190)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Connection closed..

Please help on this..

Comment: Index 8452396 out of bounds for length 8452396. arrays are 0 based, meaning the valid indices vary from 0 to (length - 1). You are using length as index

Comment: also: the issue is in your RConnection class, but you don't show that.

Comment: I have the impression that `RConnection` is a class from library... based on tags - probably data error or too big (just guessing)

Comment: having a similar issue when passing a large amount of data. There probably is a limit on the variable size.